# Laravel Missing required parameters for [Route: editGallery] [URI: editGallery/{gallery_id}]

Tags: ajax, laravel

i have some problem with my code

Here is the error

> ErrorException in UrlGenerationException.php line 17: Missing required parameters for [Route: editGallery] [URI: editGallery/{gallery_id}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\GMS\resources\views\editGallery.blade.php)

i'm trying to pass data from view to controller using ajax, here my ajax code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var gallery_id = "gallery_id_{{ $data->gallery_id }}"
        $('#editGallery{{ $data->gallery_id }}').click(function(){
            //{{ route('editGallery', $data->gallery_id) }}
            window.location.href = "editGallery/"+{{ $data->gallery_id }};
        });
    });
</script>
```

here is my code for route

```
Route::get('/editGallery/{gallery_id}', [
  'uses' => 'GalleryController@getEditGallery',
  'as' => 'editGallery'
]);
```

and the last one is my controller code

```
public function getEditGallery(Request $request){
    $galleryData = DB::SELECT("SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE gallery_id = " . $request->gallery_id);
    //dd($request->gallery_id);
    return view('editGallery', compact('galleryData'));
}
```

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
window.location.href = "editGallery/"+{{ $data->gallery_id }};
```

It seems `$data->gallery_id` is empty, so it doesn't pass any value to your route.

Also, do not generate JS with PHP. It's terrible practice for so many reasons.

Comment: no, its not empty..

here is the code when i inspect

$('#editGallery16').click(function(){
      //http://localhost:8000/editGallery/16
      window.location.href = "editGallery/"+16;
     });

Comment: Well, error message says you do not pass a parameter to the route. So route is working and there is no any parameter. What URL do you see in a browser when you click the link and get an error?

Comment: nvm its done, because //dd($request->gallery_id); and become //localhost:8000/editGallery/16
i delete it

Answer (score 0):

Why are you generating your edit link with Javascript?

I assume you have some kind of index-page where you could just output a link like this:

`<a href="editGallery/{{ $gallery->id }}">Edit Gallery</a>`